# Error Cannot Convert 'int (*)[3]' to 'Edge *' (Struct)

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

Hello i have a problem with my code, actually it works from c but not for c++, its got error message. 
i tried searching google and these threads but i didn't find anything. if you guys find a link or something explaining how to fix the errors that would be great too. thanks!

```
99  55  C:\Users\Downloads\main.cpp [Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[3]' to 'Edge*' for argument '1' to 'Graph* createGraph(Edge*, int)'
```

iwant to print all my edge from my input user but i doesnt show up. Whats does that mean?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <string.h>

    #include <conio.h>

    #include <windows.h>

    #include <math.h>

    #include <time.h>

    #define N 5
    int bataswajar=5;

    using namespace std;

    struct Graph {
        struct Node* head[N];
    };


    struct Node {
        int dest, weight;
        struct Node* next;
    };


    struct Edge {
        int src, dest, weight;
    };

    struct Graph* createGraph(struct Edge edges[], int bataswajar){
        unsigned i;
        struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            graph->head[i] = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < bataswajar; i++)
    {   
        int src = edges[i].src;
        int dest = edges[i].dest;
        int weight = edges[i].weight;
        struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->dest = dest;
        newNode->weight = weight;
        newNode->next = graph->head[src];
        graph->head[src] = newNode;
    }
    return graph;};

void printGraph(struct Graph* graph){

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){

        struct Node* ptr = graph->head[i];
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d -> %d (%d)\t", i, ptr->dest, ptr->weight);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main (){

int pilihanUser;

            printf("\n\t\t ---------------------------------------");
            printf("\n \t\t    |               MENU            |    ");
            printf("\n \t\t    |    PERUBAHAN PETA WILAYAH     |    "); 
            printf("\n\t\t ----------------------------------------\n");
            printf("1. Membuat Rute\n");
            printf("2. Lihat Rute\n");
            printf("3. Ubah Rute\n");
            printf("Masukan Pilihan Anda : ");
            scanf("%d",&pilihanUser);
            system("cls");

            if(pilihanUser==1){
            printf("Catatan : \n");
            printf("Nomor 1 = Surabaya \n");
            printf("Nomor 2 = Jombang \n");
            printf("Nomor 3 = Jakarta \n");
            printf("Nomor 4 = Kediri \n");
            printf("Angka yang terdapat dalam kurung adalah ukuran jarak satuan KM\n");
            int Edge [4][3];
            int i, j;

            for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
                for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
                    printf("\nEnter value for Edge edges [%d][%d] : ", i, j);
                    scanf("%d", &Edge[i][j]);
                }
            }

            printf("\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            }

            else if (pilihanUser==2){
                int Edge [4][3];
                printf("Lihat Rute\n");
                int n = sizeof(Edge)/sizeof(Edge[0]);
                struct Graph *graph = createGraph(Edge, bataswajar);
                printGraph(graph);
                getch();
                system("cls");
            }

            else if (pilihanUser==3){
                printf("Edit Rute\n");
                getch();
                system("cls");
            }

        }
```

Comment: The type `int (*)[3]` is a pointer to an array of three `int` elements. How can this be used when you want to assign to `Edge*`?

Comment: Also please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. And please add comments on the lines in the code where you get the error.

Comment: Lastly please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)..

Comment: If this works in C but not C++ why are you translating it to C++? While C and C++ share many of the same syntaxes, there are a few false cognates and some translational dead ends. For example, you don't need to respecify `struct` every time you use a `struct` - you can just use the `struct` name, e.g. (`struct Graph* createGraph` can just be `Graph* createGraph`. You'll potentially run into an issue with your variable `int Edge[4][3]` as well because currently `Edge` also describes a `struct`. If you try to declare an `Edge` object later in `main` you'll run into an issue.